# Casting RadioButton to ViewGroup

Tags: android, classcastexception, android-radiobutton, android-viewgroup

I am receiving a classcastingexception that states RadioButton cannot be cast to ViewGroup when I transition from an activity to a fragment by clicking a RadioButton. Any suggestions, please and thanks?

```
radioFeatures selected
11-20 12:50:08.794    4339-4339/com.example.justin.myapplication V/endofmain-features﹕ endofmain-features
11-20 12:50:08.802    4339-4339/com.example.justin.myapplication D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
11-20 12:50:08.802    4339-4339/com.example.justin.myapplication W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40f2a930)
11-20 12:50:08.809    4339-4339/com.example.justin.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RadioButton cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:945)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1138)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:740)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1501)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:458)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

@Override
       //protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, ViewGroup container){
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        Log.v("Main.class", "Main.class");

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.button_tabs);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mAdapter = new CustomButtonTabs(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        radioFeatures = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioFeatures);
        radioFeatures.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View vi) {
                Log.v("radioFeatures selected", "radioFeatures selected");
                FeaturesFragment frag = new FeaturesFragment();
                android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fragTransaction.replace(R.id.radioFeatures, frag);
                fragTransaction.commit();
                Log.v("endofmain-features", "endofmain-features");
            }
        });

to the following of FeaturesFragment:

     @Override
       public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            Log.v("FeaturesFragment", "FeaturesFragment");

           // View v = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.carfeatures_list, container, false);
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.carfeatures_list, null);
            ListView lv = (ListView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.list);

            adapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(carFeaturesList, R.layout.carfeatures_list, super.getActivity());
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
            v.findViewById(R.id.featureslist);

            //Listview on item click listener
            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                    //Gets values from selected ListItem

                    String car_features = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.car_features)).getText().toString();
                    //Log.v("onCreate-car_features", car_features.toString());

                    String carfeatures_id = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.carfeatures_id)).getText().toString();
                    //Log.v("onCreate-carfeatures_id", carfeatures_id.toString());

                    String model_id = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.model_id)).getText().toString();
                    //Log.v("onCreate-model_id", model_id.toString());

                    String carfeatures_desc = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.carfeatures_desc)).getText().toString();
                    //Log.v("onCreate-carfeats_desc", carfeatures_desc.toString());

                    Boolean b = Boolean.valueOf(TAG_CARID);
                    if (b == true) {
                        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                    }

                    //Colors the selected listview item
                    if (previouslySelectedItem != null) {
                        previouslySelectedItem.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                        Log.v("previouslySelectedItem", "!=null");
                        Log.v("position", Integer.toString(position));
                    }

                    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                    Log.v("position", Integer.toString(position));
                    Log.v("outofif-view", view.toString());
                    previouslySelectedItem = view;
                }
            });

            //Calls async task to get json
            new GetCarFeatures().execute();

            Log.v("return called-Features", "return called");
           // Log.v("container-features", container.toString());
            return v;
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `RadioButton` doesn't derive from `ViewGroup`..

> java.lang.Object
>
> ↳ android.view.View
>
> ↳ android.widget.TextView
>
> ↳ android.widget.Button
>
> ↳ android.widget.CompoundButton
>
> ↳ android.widget.RadioButton

Here's the docs showing the inheritance:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioButton.html

Instead of passing in `R.id.radioFeatures` to `fragTransaction.replace` you should pass in the id of the layout that contains the `RadioButton`.

Comment: Like fragTransaction.replace(R.layout.button_tabs, frag); ?? Expected resource type to be one of id, id is the error.

Comment: Hard to say without seeing your layout file, but try replacing `R.id.radioFeatures` with `R.id.pager`.

Comment: Awesome! Wow. Thank you!!